# How to deploy a Java/Maven application to a local server using Azure pipelines?

Tags: java, azure-devops

I have a Java application running on Maven, it runs well and i have deployed it to a local server manually and is running as intended.

How can I deploy it to a local server using Azure DevOps?

All the options that i am finding there point to Azure App Services or similar, My company has their own deployment environment to deploy this.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out below solutions to deploy a java application to local server.

1,  Use self-hosted agent.

- Create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) on you local server machine, or a local machine which can access to the server machine.
- Create a azure pipeline. [Example for yaml pipeline](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/yaml/#task-3-adding-a-yaml-build-definition). [Example for Classic UI pipeline](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/continuousintegration/)
- Use [Maven Authenticate task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline if you use azure artifact feeds. Use [Maven task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) in your pipeline to build your maven application. See example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/java?view=azure-devops).
- Use [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the built application to the local server folder. You can use [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops).
- Configure your pipeline to Run on your self-hosted agent.

See below simple example:

trigger:
- master

```
pool: Default #select the agent pool where you self-hosted agent resides.

steps:
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  ...configuration...
- task: Maven@3
  ...configuration...
- task: CopyFiles@2
  ...configuration...
```

2, Use Deployment group and release pipeline

- Create a [Deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#create-a-deployment-group) and [add your local server to the deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#deploy-agents-to-a-deployment-group) as deployment target.
- Create a build pipeline to build your maven application. Refer to above solution.
- Use [publish build artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to publish the built application as artifacts.
  See below simple example:

  ```
    pool: 
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest #run pipeline on cloud agent. 

    steps:
    - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
        ...configuration...
    - task: Maven@3
        ..configuration...
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      ...configuration...
  ```
- Create a [Release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/define-multistage-release-process?view=azure-devops).
- Add a [deployment group job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-group-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) to deploy your maven application to the local machine in the deployment group.

The main idea is to create a connection between azure devops and your local server machine using self-hosted agent or deployment group.